# Fetching several values from the same column in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. One that lists all objects (object) and one that contains the hierarchy for the objects (hierarchy).

```
Object table:
ID   | Description | ClassID
------------------------------
0001 | Room 1A     | 1000
0002 | Floor 1     | 1001
0003 | Room 1B     | 1000
0004 | Building 01 | 1002
```

Where classID specifies the type of object (room=1000, floor=1001 or building=1002)

```
Hierarchy table:
RelationID | parentid | child ID | level
1          | 0004     | 0002     |   1
2          | 0004     | 0001     |   2
3          | 0002     | 0001     |   1
```

Where level specifies the hierarchical level of the child. E.g. if I'm searching all buildings then (1 --> child (floor) , 2--> grandchild (room)).

So I would like to fetch the description from the object table for all the rooms, the floor and the building they are in.

E.g.

```
Room | Floor | Bldg
-------------------
1A   |   1   |  01
1B   |   1   |  01
2A   |   2   |  01
2B   |   2   |  01
1A   |   1   |  02
```

etc.
How can I go about doing this?

Comment: "all buildings then (1 --> child (floor) , 2--> grandchild (room))" does this mean your `parentid ` will always be building id and child id can be floor id or room id based on level? can you post the actual data in the tables

Comment: @ughai I added some sample data to the tables above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join `ObjectTable` and `HierarchyTable` multiple times like this.

```
SELECT B.Description, F.Description, R.Description
FROM ObjectTable B
    INNER JOIN HierarchyTable HT1
        ON B.ID = HT1.parentid
    INNER JOIN ObjectTable F
        ON F.ID = HT1.childid
    INNER JOIN HierarchyTable HT2
        ON HT1.childid = HB2.parentid
    INNER JOIN ObjectTable R
        ON R.ID = HT2.childid
WHERE B.ClassID = 1002
    AND F.ClassID=1001
    AND R.ClassID =1000
    AND HT1.level = 1
    AND HT2.level = 1
```

**EDIT**

Only filter `Level = 1` is required. grandchild records from hierarchy is not needed as we traverse child to child

Answer (score 1):

You can use such query to get the data:

```
SELECT Room.Description as Room, Floor.Description as Floor, Buildings.Description as Bldg
FROM ObjectTable Buildings 
    INNER JOIN Hierarchy BuildingFloor ON Buildings.ID = BuildingFloor.ParentId AND BuildingFloor.level = 1
    INNER JOIN ObjectTable Floor ON BuildingFloor.ChildId = Floor.ID
    INNER JOIN Hierarchy FloorRoom ON Floor.ID = FloorRoom.ParentId AND FloorRoom.level = 2
    INNER JOIN ObjectTable Room ON FloorRoom.ChildId = Room.ID
WHERE Buildings.ClassID = 1002 AND Floors.ClassID=1001 AND Rooms.ClassID =1000
```

I don't fully understand where and how you use `level` field, so this part of query might be not needed

Comment: it's interesting that you used only `level` initially. Based on the schema and description i suspect that one of `level` and  `ClassID` is redundant. hard to say for sure without actual data

Comment: @ughai If there are no multi level hierarchies then there is no need to provide either `level` or `ClassID` restrictions, but it hard to tell exactly without seeing the data

Comment: What i meant was that it looks like both `level` or `ClassID` kind of mean the same thing. why have both of them together in the schema.

Comment: @ughai Yes, you are right, at least one of them (most likely `level`) seems to be redundant, unless there are some business rules that we don't know about related to this field.

Comment: The level column allows me to use the building as a start point for my search since it shows me the floors as well as the rooms. Without the level I would have to connect twice between the building and the floor then the floor and the room

Comment: @TarekMerachli - Thanks for your explaination, the way we have constructed our queries, we only need `level = 1` for this.